# Got an ad about YouTube Red, how to bypass this to download music?

Tags: youtube

I just downloaded a free YouTube app to my Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 (Android) that was supposed to let me download their music videos. But when trying to use it, all I get is a big ad for YouTube Red, which I don't need.

How do I get past this ad so that I can download music?

Comment: To me it looks like YouTube itself is blocking the app. If you really want to download content from YouTube you can use websites such as clipconverter.cc

Comment: Umm, where did you download this app? YouTube app itself is free, and it does support download some music videos in some countries, but I never had a big ad for YouTube Red when using it.

Answer (score 0):

First, If you wan't to block Youtube's ads in the app, you will need a rooted device and a new framework for your phone.

Xposed is the ultimate app for making modifications to your android phone. If you can get Xposed installed and have it working, download an app called "Youtube Adaway".

Youtube Adaway is an Xposed module that works like a charm.

If you wan't to download music off of Youtube, you will need to use a website like mp3fiber.com.

Simply copy and paste the URL of the video/song you want to download, and it will get your mp3.

Comment: Thank you, Ryan. I don't mind looking  at ads if i can click x and get rid  of them. Problem  here is a full page  ad with no x that seems to be blocking the supposed function of the app. (which  claimed able to download  youtube )  Mystery, frustration.  Like most apps, it arrives with zero instructions  on w

Comment: My advice is to use an ad blocker. Ads are evil and what has cause Google to become greedy. Every video (if it's advertising friendly or not), I get an ad. Sometimes the ads are unskippable. That's why I don't get on YouTube anymore. Sometimes Google will even bypass the adblockers. It is a shame. If an adblocker doesn't even work, then just stay off YouTube.